# Select, Color Range: error message - no pixels are more than 50% selected

Tags: adobe-photoshop, background-removal

I am trying to remove a green background from an image. To do so, I open an image on Photoshop CC 2015, go to `Select` and then `Color Range`. I then choose `Greens` and click `Ok`. I get the following error message:

`Warning: No pixels are more than 50% selected. The selection edges will not be visible.`

And nothing happens. What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this error?

Thanks for helping! :D

Comment: What does the selection preview show?

Comment: @Cai it shows the part of the image that will be selected, I cannot change `Fuziziness` or `Range` however

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is working as intended. If the result would produce a mask that's less than 50% opaque than the marching ants don't appear but it is selected and if you apply a mask you'll see it working as intended. Basically, you'll get a white to gray mask with no dark grays or black areas completely removing the green. This probably means your green screen or select color range wasn't done well.

In any case, this isn't really the best way to mask out a green screen. You should just duplicate the Green Channel, adjust the levels of the duplicate, and refine a little as needed with brushes.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I am very new to Photoshop and using select color range seemed to be the easiest solution. I will try following your suggestions!

Answer (score -1):

I put the Feather as 0% and that fixed my problem.

Comment: Hello user174956, welcome to GDSE. We typically look for long answers here, that don't just explain the _how_ but also the _why_. Would you be so kind as to [edit] your answer to include more information as to why you think your answer solves OP's problem, and maybe a screenshot of the settings pane?